# What is the significance of the Ki and Ke prefixes

Tags: windows, api, kernel

I’ve encountered these kernel mode functions in Windows and want to know what do they represent by their prefixes ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptions of the main prefixes are shown in the table below (taken from the Windows Internals book and http://bsodtutorials.blogspot.com/2013/10/windows-api-function-prefixes.html). Variations of these prefixes are used for internal functions - either the first letter of the prefix plus an `i` (e.g. `Ki` = "Kernel Internal") or the full prefix followed by `p` (e.g. `Psp` = "Process Support Internal").

| Prefix | Component |
| --- | --- |
| Alpc | Advanced Local Inter-Process Communication |
| Cc | Common Cache |
| Cm | Configuration Manager |
| Dbg | Kernel debug support |
| Dbgk | Debugging Framework for User-Mode |
| Em | Errata Manager |
| Etw | Event Tracing for Windows |
| Ex | Executive support routines |
| FsRtl | File System driver Run-Time Library |
| Hal | Hardware Abstraction Layer |
| Hv | Hive Library |
| Hvl | Hypervisor Library |
| Io | I/O Manager |
| Kd | Kernel Debugger |
| Ke | Kernel |
| Kse | Kernel Shim Engine |
| Lsa | Local Security Authority |
| Mm | Memory Manager |
| Nt | NT System Services (accessible from user mode through system calls) |
| Ob | Object Manager |
| Pf | Prefetcher |
| Po | Power Manager |
| PoFx | Power Framework |
| Pp | PnP Manager |
| Ppm | Processor Power Manager |
| Ps | Process Support |
| Rtl | Run-time Library |
| Se | Security Reference Monitor |
| Sm | Store Manager |
| Tm | Transaction Manager |
| Ttm | Terminal Timeout Manager |
| Vf | Verifier (Driver Verifier) |
| Whea | Windows Hardware Error Architecture |
| Wmi | Windows Management Instrumentation |
| Wdi | Windows Diagnostic Infrastructure |
| Zw | Similar to NT, but sets access mode to Kernel, which in turn eliminates any parameter validation. |